# ERROR ==> EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/home/$User/.ssh'

Tags: lando

after install lando and star first project I get this error and I cant use sudo !!!

An error occurred while starting up your app!
Here are a few things you can try to get back into a good state:

■ Try running lando rebuild
■ Try restarting in debug mode lando restart -vvv
■ Try checking the logs with lando logs

If those fail then consult the troubleshooting materials:

Or post your issue to Slack or GitHub

ERROR ==> EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/home/baker/.ssh'

```
 
     $lando start
     Let's get this party started! Starting app hello-lando...
     ERROR ==\> EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/home/baker/.ssh' message=EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/home/baker/.ssh', stack=Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/home/baker/.ssh'
     at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:1047:3)
     at Object.readdirSync (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1266:35)
     at AsyncEvents.\<anonymous\> (/snapshot/cli/plugins/lando-core/app.js)
     at AsyncEvents.handle (/snapshot/cli/lib/events.js)
     at /snapshot/cli/lib/events.js
     From previous event:
     at AsyncEvents.emit (/snapshot/cli/lib/events.js)
     at /snapshot/cli/lib/app.js
      From previous event:
      at App.init (/snapshot/cli/lib/app.js)
      at initAndReport (/snapshot/cli/lib/app.js)
      at App.start (/snapshot/cli/lib/app.js)
      at Object.run (/snapshot/cli/plugins/lando-core/tasks/start.js)
      From previous event:
      at /snapshot/cli/lib/cli.js
      From previous event:
      at Object.handler (/snapshot/cli/lib/cli.js)
      at Object.runCommand (/snapshot/cli/node_modules/yargs/lib/command.js:238:44)
      at Object.parseArgs \[as \_parseArgs\] (/snapshot/cli/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1063:30)
      at Function.get \[as argv\] (/snapshot/cli/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1004:21)
      at Cli.init (/snapshot/cli/lib/cli.js)
      at Cli.run (/snapshot/cli/lib/cli.js)
      at Object.\<anonymous\> (/snapshot/cli/bin/lando.js)
      at Module.\_compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1887:22)
      at Object.Module.\_extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
      at Function.Module.\_load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
      at Function.runMain (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1940:12)
      at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47, errno=-13, syscall=scandir, code=EACCES,         path=/home/baker/.ssh, __stackCleaned__=true

     ██╗   ██╗██╗  ██╗     ██████╗ ██╗  ██╗██╗
     ██║   ██║██║  ██║    ██╔═══██╗██║  ██║██║  
     ██║   ██║███████║    ██║   ██║███████║██║  
     ██║   ██║██╔══██║    ██║   ██║██╔══██║╚═╝  
     ╚██████╔╝██║  ██║    ╚██████╔╝██║  ██║██╗  
      ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝     ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝

    An error occurred while starting up your app!
    Here are a few things you can try to get back into a good state:

    ■ Try running lando rebuild
    ■ Try restarting in debug mode lando restart -vvv
    ■ Try checking the logs with lando logs

     If those fail then consult the troubleshooting materials:

     ■ https://docs.lando.dev/help/logs.html
     ■ https://docs.lando.dev/help/updating.html

     Or post your issue to Slack or GitHub

      ■ Slack - https://launchpass.com/devwithlando
      ■ GitHub - https://github.com/lando/lando/issues/new/choose

     ERROR ==\> EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/home/baker/.ssh'
```

```
$ lando start
ERROR ==> EACCES: permission denied
```

lando start = permission denied ,every time.
what is the problem?

Comment: It looks like lando does not have permission to your home .ssh directory. That is good as .ssh usually have 700 (see this for more details https://superuser.com/questions/215504/permissions-on-private-key-in-ssh-folder)